# Create a Dynamic UI in Android from json Template

Tags: android, json, user-interface, android-activity

On the App start, I will download the data from the web-server and store  it in shared-preference, now what I want is depending upon the json template dynamically create the UI form/Activity in android.Can any one suggest me how to implement this.

```
 {  
       "templates":[  
          {  
             "name":"Default",
             "default":true,
             "fields":[  
                {  
                   "type":"textbox",
                   "label":"Your e-mail",
                   "metadataIPTC":"234",
                   "required":true,
                   "regex":"\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\b"
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

Comment: As I'm trying to create, it is first time implementing this, if there are any tutorial/example you can provide me @ianhanniballake

Comment: Have a look on this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086448/react-native-server-driven-ui/68200157#68200157](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086448/react-native-server-driven-ui/68200157#68200157)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML layouts are converted to Java objects at runtime, so you can simply write an XML which has a container Layout ( say *Linear Layout* ), inflate it at runtime, and add view programatically depending on the information received from server.

An example would be :
Creating a layout, and setting that as the Activity's content view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container"
   />
```

Then somewhere in code:
Let's say that after parsing the JSON you have a **List<Field> fields;**

```
  LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
  for (Field f: fields) {
    if (f.getType().equals("textbox")) {
        TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
        txtView.setText("Your e-mail");
        txtView.setId(1);//need for better use
        linearLayout.addView(txtView);
    } else if (f.getType().equals("button")) {
        //create a button similarly as above,and add it to the layout
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample example.

Comment: About parsing the Json ?

Comment: I know parsing json, but the problem how to show the UI

Comment: can we have to check for each controls?

Comment: how to fetch value from this please somebody tell me

Answer (score 1):

I think you’re asking about Server Driven UI, please go through this link to know more about it:
https://proandroiddev.com/dynamic-screens-using-server-driven-ui-in-android-262f1e7875c1

Comment: Could you edit this answer to add a synopsis about what the link says? We generally discourage link-only answers, since the inevitable link rot can render answers useless if there is no other information.